# Dystopian future book: false news reports, personal ID device called smokes

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

The book was written like late 90's to pre-2008. was dystopian future I think it was called "Jazzed" but can't find it by that name.  Primary character was a young female.  Book could have been juvenile fiction. The internet was described as a place where people gave false news reports. People carried a personal ID device called smokes. You could write computer code that interfaced with biologicals.

Ringing any bells?  It was remarkably prophetic in hindsight.

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=Jazz&type=Fiction+Titles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Melissa Scott, The Jazz (2000)

*Publisher's Weekly* mentions

> Tin Lizzy, another of the author's highly competent hackers with a
>   heart of gold, makes her living producing virtual background scenarios
>   for *the jazz*, the newest Internet art form: an inspired combination of
>   personality journalism, gossip, cyberpranks and outright lies.

*Booklist* includes this in their review:

> [...] long ago, when a teenage prostitute, she encountered Gerretty, stole his *smoke*, and was viciously punished by several years in a harsh prison.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  Highly recommended reading. It's like an outline of modern day culture LOL

Comment: @user74020: If you think it is the right one, please click on the checkmark by the voting buttons to accept it.